# How do I flush() in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io, stream, flush

I'm writing a lot of data to a file it may take a long time so I want to write the contents to file as soon I call  my `save()` function. Currently the file size (I'm watching from Windows Explorer) stay at 0 bytes size until <s>program</s> writing terminates.

I tried both:

```
fileOut = new StreamWriter(fileName);
fileOut.AutoFlush = true;
```

and

```
fileOut.Write(contents);
fileOut.Flush();
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You're probably trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical symptom of not closing the stream. Wrap your resource usages in a using statement, like always.

Flushing does not do what you think it does. It does not make data visible to other programs. It forces it do disk. This is not your problem.

It doesn't matter what's on disk. What matters is what the Windows File Cache presents to other programs. File contents can be in memory and still be synchronized between applications.

[The metadata behavior (length, times, ...) is strange on Windows.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/26/10251026.aspx) Turns out that enumerating a directory can return stale data. Directly looking at a file (opening its Properties Window) should return accurate information at all times.

The linked Raymond Chen article has a workaround you can use to force current information to be made visible immediately.

Comment: "It forces it do disk" that's exactly what I'm trying to do. The other program I seen the file size stay at 0 size is the Windows Explorer itself. Shouldn't file size change there?

Comment: @Jack You're still holding a lock on the file, so they still can't access it until you're done...

Comment: @usr It sounds like he wants to be able to read from the file while the program is still writing to it.